# Why do i have to click this radio button twice to set it active in react

Tags: reactjs

Below is my code for handling the onClick for a radio button that uses images as its label

```
function foo(props) {
let id = props.id
id = id.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <input type="radio" name="foo" id={props.id} value={props.id} onClick={()=>{props.handle(id)}}/>
        
      <label for={props.id}>
        <Image src={props.src} style={foo} className="zoom" rounded />
      </label>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

This is the code handling the state change for it

```
const [foo,setFooState] = useState("foo")

function updateState(e){
setFooState(e)
}
```

I am currently having an issue where I have to click the image twice in order for the radio button to be set as active

Comment: Can you add your complete code or sandbox?

Comment: This is perplexing as I tried to recreate the issue in the sandbox and it was unable to recreate it. However, I suspect it has something to do with the onclick as when I removed it it works again

Comment: have you tried to pass props.id?  like this: onClick={()=>{props.handle(props.id)}}

Comment: Yep, the same issue. The state manages to update every time on the first click. however, the radio button does not get set to active until the second click

Comment: then you should handle the checked property of radio, like: const [myRadio, setRadio]=useState(false);     and in radio button <input type="radio" name="foo" id={props.id} value={props.id} onClick={()=>{props.handle(id)}} checked={myRadio} onChange={()=>setRadio(!myRadio)}/>

Comment: Hi bakar, thanks for the help however it still requires clicking twice to set active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found the issue which is i am passing the state change 2 parent up and that is causing some unintended issue.

Comment: Did You find the solution for it?